# Kali doesn’t work on LCD Screen

Tags: kali

So my problem is I’ve installed Kali Linux on my Raspberry Pi 4 and bought a small LCD Screen for it.
I changed the config file as they described it in the manual.
When I try to boot it, I only get a weird white and grey picture. But when I try to plug it into my normal monitor everything works.
Any ideas on what I’m doing wrong.

(The LCD Screen is specifically for advertised as functional with Kali Linux)

[image]

Comment: kali is for Linux experts.

Comment: `The LCD Screen is specifically for advertised as functional with Kali Linux` perhaps you did it wrong then

Comment: I didn’t ask for advise on if I should use it just what I did wrong there. As I said kali linux working isn’t the problem since it works on my normal monitor. I configured the config file EXACTLY like the manual told me to. I even wrote an email to the company asking how it would be configured right and followed the steps.